# Characteristic polynomial splits problem

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Problem: let T be a linear mapping on a finite-dimensional vector space V, and suppose there exists an ordered basis $\beta$ for V such that $[T]_\beta$ is an upper triangular matrix. Prove that the characteristic polynomial for T splits.

Proof: the characteristic polynomial is given by $f(t)=| A-\lambda I$|, since $A=[T]_\beta$ is upper triangular, we can write it as $f(t)=\Pi_{i=1}^{n}([T]_{\beta_{ii}}-t)$. Hence the characteristic polynomial splits.

> Question: Anything failed to consider?

Comment: Lookin' good there, Beacon,***+1!***.

Comment: Seem fine to me.

Comment: To the OP; I think you don't understand the root of the problem. When one says that a polynomial $P$ splits, it is relative to a fixed underlying field $K$. Indeed, there is always an extension of $K$ in which $P$ splits. In the considered case, there is a basis of your $K$-vector space in which the representative matrix $T$ is ​​triangular; that is important is that the entries of $T$ and of its characteristic polynomial are in $K$; then $P$ splits in $K$. More generally, the characteristic polynomial of a matrix $A\in M_n(K)$ splits in $K$ IFF their eigenvalues are in $K$.

Comment: Conclusion. If you don't say a word about the underlying field, then your proof is worthless.

Comment: @loupblanc thanks for the head up, I didn't consider that.